# Plugin/settings configurations for IntelliJ Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I use IntelliJ Idea and have two projects: server in clojure and android client. Both have different plugin sets and tool windows are bloated. I have clojure REPL tool window when working on android and android tool window when working on server.

Is there a way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to configure it by using multiple apps (OS X) by changing configuration of config and plugins folders in App > Contents > bin > idea.properties. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-and-ide-settings.html

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA 15, you can right-click a toolwindow and select "Remove from sidebar".

Having different sets of plugins for different projects is not supported as of IntelliJ IDEA 15.